# I'm looking for a movie about a weird religious journey

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for a movie that I saw a few years ago. It was a story about a boy going on a journey to find someone or something, and one of the landmarks he has to find is a hill with a huge crucifix-shape carved into it. He had one or two companions with him, one was a girl.

In the beginning the boy tries to rob an abandoned church, but he meets someone there. She lets him take some chalices, and he does. I think the boy lives in a car junkyard with a group of other kids and people. The leader makes the kids go out and steal every day. He goes back to the church everyday and the woman there teaches him how to read using the bible. She tells him that he needs to go on a journey, and he should use the bible as a map.

At one point in the movie, the main character wanted to go to this arcade place. Everyone there had to wear glasses and they were very specifically told not to take the glasses off. The girl did, and saw that what everyone thought was a cool and fun place was actually a prison. The glasses altered everyone's vision and made the prisoners invisible. Because she took the glasses off, she was taken away and held captive for some time.

In the end, the boy jumps off a cliff and into a body of water. He gets pulled out by someone in a boat using a fishing net.

This movie could've been made anywhere from the 80s to 2006. There were terrible green screen effects. I'm sorry I cant be any more descriptive, please help me find this movie!!

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for the Christian film [The Wylds](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1336619/combined) (AKA The Adventures of Chris Fable) from 2010.

> Chris, a runaway child, lives with a group of misfits in a junkyard, stealing to survive. When a traveling preacher tells him that his father is alive and wants him to come home, Chris must leave his family of thieves and venture into the wilderness in search of his father and a better life. Join Chris on an action-packed adventure as he outwits bandits, escapes swamp monsters, battles evil robots, and learns valuable lessons about choosing the right path in life. A contemporary allegory inspired by John Bunyan's "[The Pilgrim's Progress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Pilgrim's_Progress)."

Here's the trailer where you can see some of the scenes you mentioned, the amateurish effects and a somewhat... familiar title design in the end (someone get Rowling's lawyers on the phone):